# Data Source Explorer is missing in Eclipse Juno 4.2.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using eclipse juno 4.2.2 version.

I am unable to open perspective for Data Source Explorer.

Is any software is missing in my eclipse. Can you please provide steps to install if it is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data source explorer is not available in (JUNO)Eclipse classic 4.2.2 version.

Download (JUNO)Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers version to access Data Source Explorer.